# URL rewriting for Office 365

Tags: office-365, url-rewriting

Is there any way for URL rewriting in Office 365? If yes, share the steps for the same and useful links.

Comment: What kind of URL-rewriting are you refering to?

Comment: I have a url or domain that is very long! How can I create a shorter url that acts as an alias.

Comment: You can just create a friendly url then. Provided you are using managed navigation.

Comment: Is it your domain that is to long? like the "zzz.sharepoint.com"? If so, no there is no way to change this in Office 365. You could possibly add an internal DNS entry that points an alias to the full URL but that would only work where your DNS-server is used

Comment: For example i have http://abc.sharepoint.com/
Whenever user enter this url, the user should be redirected to http://abc.sharepoint.com/site1/SitePages/Home.aspx 
without going to http://abc.sharepoint.com/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

currently there is no friendly name. I understand that within a business having an unrelated url to your standard name is not friendly.

usually if that is the case you should than have DNS setup. If so you can create a CNAME entry in DNS.

so the friendly name could be:

the main website is in mvc hosted on azure or internally that is called:

> http://www.google.com

but you also have other subsite called:

> http://myWorld.google.com
>
> http://family.google.com
>
> http://support.google.com

and now you have a 365 site at

> https://google.sharepoint.com

but you want it inline with the other sites within the business keeping it clean so:

within DNS create a CNAME that looks like the following:

> http://intranet.google.com that points to
>   https://google.sharepoint.com

the final stage is to update your "A records".

the "A recods" would be similar the the CNAME but this time you have the friendly name that points to the 365 ip address instead.

> http://intranet.google.com that points to 1.2.1.365

**CNAME in DNS**

> https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Domains-Archive/Domains-Explained/what-is-a-cname-263/

**A Record in cPanel**

> http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/updating-an-a-record-in-cpanel/